# Inadequate indexing of pandas array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anaconda

I've got a pandas `DataFrame` in the `result` variable and want to extract some rows from it, specifically, group them by pairs of `id`s and select rows, corresponding to minimum `score`s.

Here is the code:

```
gb = result.groupby(['id1', 'id2'], sort=False, group_keys=False, as_index=False)
result1 = result.loc[gb['score'].idxmin()].dropna()
```

I've stopped the code in the debugger to check results for correctness. Results are weird.

```
>>> gb['score'].idxmin().shape
Out[11]: (1800L,)

>>> result1.shape
Out[12]: (1810, 6)
```

Where do those 10 rows come from?!

More, I have run exactly the same code in Jupyter notebook interactively on the same data file, and have got 1800 rows.

I am using Anaconda with all updates. Here is the version string

```
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:58:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: Indeed, the problem was in non-unique index. The dataframe `result` was obtained from `pd.concat([df1, df2])`. Adding `ingore_index=True` has solved the issue. And Jupyter cell contained that `ignore_index=True`, indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`result` must have duplicate labels in its index. For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

result = pd.DataFrame({'X':np.arange(6)}, index=list('ABAAEF'))
print(result)
#    X
# A  0
# B  1
# A  2
# A  3
# E  4
# F  5
```

One index label, `'A'`, corresponds to three rows

```
print(result.loc[['A']])
#    X
# A  0
# A  2
# A  3
```

---

To ensure the labels returned by `idxmin` correspond to unique rows, you need `result` to have a unique index. Either use `setindex` to generate such an index, or call `reset_index` to give `result` a generic integer Index:

```
result = result.reset_index()
#   index  X
# 0     A  0
# 1     B  1
# 2     A  2
# 3     A  3
# 4     E  4
# 5     F  5

gb = result.groupby(['id1', 'id2'], sort=False, group_keys=False, as_index=False)
result1 = result.loc[gb['score'].idxmin()].dropna()
```

---

An easy way to check if your DataFrame has a unique index is to inspect the `Index.is_unique` property:

```
In [53]: result = pd.DataFrame({'X':np.arange(6)}, index=list('ABAAEF'))
In [54]: result.index.is_unique
Out[54]: False

In [55]: df = pd.DataFrame({'X':np.arange(6)})
In [56]: df.index.is_unique
Out[56]: True
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. But why does exactly the same code, run in an interactive Jupyter cell on the same data file, return 1800 rows?

Comment: Unless there is some use of randomness in your code, I have no idea why the result would be different when run interactively in Jupyter. If only one of the results can be correct and you can figure out which result is wrong and make a reproducible example, then you have the makings of a bug report ([Pandas](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)/[Jupyter](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues)). But in any case, the symptom you describe above points to a non-unique index.